# Elixir Metaprogramming: Inject a list of function calls into a function body

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I have a list of tuples with the format `{:task, function_name, description}` and I want to generate a function that calls the functions defined in the tuples to override a value.

My generated function should look like:

```
def run(val) do
  val = do_something(val)
  val = do_something_else(val)
  ...

  val
end
```

Here is my current code:

```
  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do

    steps =  Module.get_attribute(env.module, :steps) |> Enum.reverse

    iteration = Enum.map steps, fn {:task, func, _} ->
      quote do
        val = unquote(func)(val)
      end
    end

    ast = quote do
      def run(val) do

        unquote(iteration)

        val
      end
    end

    ast
  end
```

But that generates the following function:

```
def(run(val)) do
  [val = it_adds_five(val), val = it_adds_ten(val)]
  val
end
```

As you can see, my function calls are inside a list and only the last function call is applied. When I pass the value `2` into the `run` function, i get `12` back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote_splicing/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote_splicing/1) instead of [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote_splicing/1) to "splice" in a list of AST nodes.

Changing:

```
def run(val) do
  unquote(iteration)
  val
end
```

to

```
def run(val) do
  unquote_splicing(iteration)
  val
end
```

Generates this AST:

```
def(run(val)) do
  val = bar(val)
  val = foo(val)
  val
end
```

for

```
@steps [
  {:task, :foo, ""},
  {:task, :bar, ""},
]
```

Comment: WOW. That fixed it! Many thanks for the quick reply :) You saved my day!